# In search of a subject in scalability issues and/or designs of web applications

Tags: web-applications, cloud, scalability, distributed-computing

In a few months I will have to start with my master thesis and after taking courses in cloud computing and distributed systems I can say that I found this topics quite interesting. 
What I would like to do here is to start a discussion that might drive me to a thesis subject.
As the title of this thread says I would like to find something in scalability of web applications.
So if you have an idea, from the simplest to the most complicated, don't hesitate to post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have seen the following possible subjects:

- Investigate the feasibility of functional programming languages for web applications.
- Try to identify typical/recurring structures in web apps that can easily be executed in parallel and devise ways that make it easier to discover such areas.
- Investigate in how far parallelism in web apps can be put into practice using the STM paradigm rather then messaging.
- SaaS/multi-tenancy, find a rather sharp border between a multi user web-app and a multi tenancy SaaS app. Stipulate the security requirements for such.
- Devise/implement an OSGi like platform in Haskell that could be the seed for cloud apps/work loads to be mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting subjects. I liked the second one that you proposed. They are also trying to convince me to do something on semantics. And I might be already convinced...

Comment: Thanks, in fact I have many more ideas. Contact me if you need some :D